# float starting from 1.0 to 2.0 increase of 0.1

Tags: c++, c

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


int  main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL,"Turkish");
for (float i=1.0; i<=2.0f; i+=0.1)  //to float 2.0 but result is to 1.9
printf("%.1f\n" ,i);
}
```

// I start from float 1.0 to 2.0 increase by 0.1 but I will finish at 2.0 instead of 1.9
// Why doesn't it end at 2.0Why doesn't it end at 2.0

```
/*
//RESULT
1,0
1,1
1,2
1,3
1,4
1,5
1,6
1,7
1,8
1,9     
*/
```

Comment: Try printing the numbers with more precision: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/-uYQ8a

Comment: to get desired output use integer loop variable (never float!) `for (int i=0;i<=10;++i) cout << 1.0 + 0.1*i;`

Comment: It does not end with 2.0, it also ends with 1.9

Comment: Read the linked thread!

Comment: Yes, but do you see why? There are extra numbers after decimal point due to floating point inaccuracies, and adding `0.1` to `1.9000002` makes it bigger than `2.0`.

Comment: I understand the problem thanks